# Using scrollTo() in GridView

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-scroll

I have a `GridView` in an `Activity` and I want to scroll the `GridView` to a specific position using the `scrollTo()` method. Specifically, scroll the `GridView` by `scrollTo()` and alert a `Dialog` in the `OnItemClickListener()`, scroll back by `scrollTo()` in `PositiveButton` click.

If I just click the items in the `GridView`, it works well, but if I click the items after scrolling the `GridView` by finger, the `GridView` will scroll to the specific position and then scroll back immediately.  I don't know why or how to deal with it.

```
gv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    { 
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) 
        { 
            gv.scrollTo(0, 200);
            AlertDialog.Builder dilog =new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            dilog.setPositiveButton("aa", new OnClickListener(){

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    gv.scrollTo(0, 0);
                }

            });
            dilog.create().show();
        } 
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

`GridView` has some [known issues](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/Cb94wmekux4/QiM1CydrcMEJ) with `scrollTo()`. Depending on your situation, there are a few [workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12852413/workarounds-for-gridview-scrollto), such as calling `smoothScrollToPosition()` or `setSelection()`.

Comment: Should probably snap grid to nearest position when user's scroll completes so that  `ScrollToPosition()` doesn't "jump" on restore.