# workarounds for GridView.scrollTo()?

Tags: android, gridview, scroll

As mentioned [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.android.devel/149329), Android's GridView.scrollTo() doesn't work. The method the solution mentioned, `setSelectedPosition`, doesn't seem to exist in [GridView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html)

`smoothScrollToPosition` does work, but I really don't want the animation.

For context, I have a `CursorAdapter`-backed `GridView`, and I want the view to "reset", i.e. scroll to the top, when I change the cursor.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I've been using `setSelection(int position)` for this, and it seems to be working just fine. To scroll to the top, just use 0 for position.

From the docs:

> If in touch mode, the item will not be selected but it will still be positioned appropriately.

**Edit:**
Added code to post `setSelection` as a Runnable:

```
albumsView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        albumsView.setSelection(0);
    }
});
```

Comment: I've tried that, no luck. Are you using a CursorAdapter? Thanks anyway.

Comment: No, just a BaseAdapter extension. Are you trying it before or after you change cursors? I'm not sure it makes a difference, but then I can't see why using a CursorAdapter rather than anything else would make a difference when simply scrolling.

Comment: Good call, thank you sooo much!! I was monkeying around with this for a long time. (literally, hours and hours). Apparently there was a problem when both calling setSelection() and changeCursor(). The order of setSelection() and changeCursor doesn't matter (both fail if just called directly in order), but it does work to post back setSelection() [ http://pastebin.com/XmM5jqD3 ]. Please update your answer with that paste :)

Comment: Also, I guess I need to wait 22 hours to award the bounty ... will do so after that time elapses.

Comment: If you're having problems with setSelection, the problem almost certainly lies in the gridview layout being in the process of being refreshed. Hence, the call to setSelection is ignored. To mitigate this problem use post (which listens for the completion the GridView layout) like this: yourGridView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        yourGridView.setSelection(0);
    }
});

Answer (score 1):

I have found that in order to reliably use gridView.setSelection(index), I have to first call gridView.setAdapter() (even if the adapter has already been set and has not changed). Like so:

```
gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);
gridView.setSelection(index);
```

Comment: Calling setAdapter will always result in the appearance of scrolling to top as the existing adapter is yanked away and replace with a new one. This os bad for performance and one should try to manipulate the existing adapter.

Comment: Wrong @slott. If the adapter is already set, this does not result in a reset. I didn't say anything about creating a new adapter or removing the old one. All I said was that, in my experience, I have to re-call setAdapter *even if the adapter has already been set* in order for setSelection to be work reliably.

Comment: I tried the other approaches here and this is the only one that worked. I was setting a  filter on the adapter and wanted the gridview to return to the top. Although the data reset properly, the image sometimes showed the wrong photo in the imageview. Thanks @mikejonesguy