# scroll a view in top of a gridview

Tags: android, gridview, scroll

i have a layout in top of a grid view as you can see and i want my layout to scroll with the grid view
but i don't know how to do it and i couldn't find any good solution to do it can anyone help me ?
i've seen lots of apps witch have this ability such az google, facebook,...

```
    <include
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        layout="@layout/activity_loading"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_loadinglayout" />

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_grid_grid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:numColumns="2"
            android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/header_update_item_width"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/header_update_item_width"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_above="@+id/activity_main_progress_bar"
            android:paddingTop="130dp">
        </GridView>
    </include>
```

Comment: This may help [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19129975/android-auto-merge-two-listview-in-one-screen/19130449#19130449) Try my answer by changing listview to gridView

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12886634/3047840

Comment: possible duplicate of [workarounds for GridView.scrollTo()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12852413/workarounds-for-gridview-scrollto)